# Hbase CopyTable Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to copy a Hbase table. I'm getting error in executing the following command because of the `':'`. I want to keep this `':'` in the table name. Can someone help me how to fix this and successfully copy the Hbase table?

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=grp:test1_bkp grp:test1

Error: 
SyntaxError: (hbase):4: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

":" is not allowed in TableName. 
From documentation.

> IllegalArgumentException - if passed a tableName is null or is made
>   of other than 'word' characters or underscores: i.e. [a-zA-Z_0-9.-:].
>   The ':' is used to delimit the namespace from the table name and can
>   be used for nothing else. Namespace names can only contain 'word'
>   characters [a-zA-Z_0-9] or '_' Qualifier names can only contain 'word'
>   characters [a-zA-Z_0-9] or '_', '.' or '-'. The name may not start
>   with '.' or '-'. Valid fully qualified table names: foo:bar,
>   namespace=>foo, table=>bar org:foo.bar, namespace=org, table=>foo.bar

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/TableName.html#isLegalFullyQualifiedTableName(byte[])